# Find nearest number in Core Data without iterating over data

Tags: ios, core-data

I know it's currently not possible to find the nearest geo-location in Core Data without loading all data and doing it manually in code,
but is it at least doable with simple numbers?
Can I, for example, have a table with entries, with the values `1, 2.5, 4`, I search for `3.6` and get back the entry with `4`?

I mean a fetchRequest, with a NSPredicate which does the work already in SQL so the objects don't have to be loaded and transformed into Swift/Objective-C Objects, which can be very expensive if you have something like 100'000 entries.

I couldn't find anything in NSPredicate for that, so I assume it isn't possible? Is that correct?!

Comment: how about transforming the value first, then search for the nearest value, 4 in your case?

Comment: @pmk What do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to fetch with a predicate like this:

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"attribute >= 3.6")
```

sorted by `attribute` ascending:

```
fetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"attribute", ascending:true)
```

but limited to the first result:

```
fetch.fetchLimit = 1
```

This should return the object with `attribute` value closest to and greater than or equal to your desired value.

Then repeat the fetch, but with the predicate and sort order reversed:

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"attribute < 3.6")
fetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"attribute", ascending:false)
fetch.fetchLimit = 1
```

which will return the object with the `attribute` value closest to but less than your desired value.  You will then have to choose which of the objects actually has closest value.

Comment: Cumbersome but actually not that bad. Nice thinking. Still wish there would be a more performant way than:
   2 * (SQL fetch + Object Mapping)
+ 1 * Code Calculation

Comment: I tried this even with an indexed attribute and it's actually *much* slower than a conventional binary search. Therefore I hope there is a better answer to that question. :-/

Comment: I gave up and accepted your answer. You did good work, the Apple guys did not.

Comment: @Jan I agree - the above is a clunky solution.  If only Apple would extend the possible predicates and sort descriptors - what you want is hardly unusual.

Comment: Hardly unusual is an understatement. If you have e. g. TimeInterval timestamps, how often would you search for something like exactly 1294.21784835 seconds? Makes almost never sense, it's 101 in programming to almost never _exactly_ compare floating point numbers. :-/